# Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute' attribute in new Azure Functions project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I get many error messages when I want to deploy my new project to Azure.

AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute("Newfunctions")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute("Release")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute("1.0.0")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute("Newfunctions")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute("Newfunctions")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.0.0")]

// Generated by the MSBuild WriteCodeFragment class.
```

Error messages:

```
Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute' attribute [Newfunctions]
Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute' attribute [Newfunctions]
Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute' attribute [Newfunctions]
Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute' attribute [Newfunctions]
Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute' attribute [Newfunctions]
Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute' attribute [Newfunctions]
Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute' attribute [Newfunctions]
```

And another one in AssemblyAttributes.cs:

```
// <autogenerated />
using System;
using System.Reflection;
[assembly: global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute(".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1", FrameworkDisplayName = "")]
```

Error message:

```
Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute [Newfunctions]
```

I have nothing added or changed in the assembly classes. I have only installed the Azure Functions extension and PlayFab Explorer extension in Visual Studio Code. In addition, I have added the nuget packages PlayFabAllSDK and PlayFabCloudScriptPlugin to my project. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

What is wrong with my project? How can I fix these error messages?

[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brx7V.png)

Newfunctions.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.7"/>
<PackageReference Include="PlayFabAllSDK" Version="1.81.200914"/>
<PackageReference Include="PlayFabCloudScriptPlugin" Version="1.53.190627-alpha"/>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<None Update="host.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Update="local.settings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: you need to set `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>` in your csproj

Comment: Where exactly should I set <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo> ? Should I add this somewhere in Newfunctions.csproj?

Comment: add it the project which is creating its assembly info twice.

Answer (score 11):

Adding `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>` to the project file didn't work for me.

What did however work was to delete the **bin** and **obj** folders in all the projects where the error occured. Then restart Visual Studio and try to run again.

Comment: also fixed the problem with my .net WPF project thanks

Comment: I also had to delete the `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs`. Context: I copied a SwaggerHub autogenerated project into a VS Code folder.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the root cause was in attempting to create a new project within another project's folder (accidentally).  As soon as I moved the new project to the same folder level as the first project  the errors disappeared.

When we compile a project, the obj/debug/(Framework Name) folder autogenerates files. One of them is "ProjectName.AssemblyInfo.cs".  This file has attributes for: Company, Configuration, Copyright, Description, FileVersion, InformationalVersion, and 4 Assembly attributes.  The compiler expects the project's folder and all subfolders to only have one of these files.